# How does ruby hierarchy work when we define a method without class and nested classes?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, the class hierarchy seems very arbitrary. For example, we can define methods directly in a module without a class, or we can even define a class within a class. Can anyone explain how these two scenarios work?

Comment: BTW, what’s the problem to [define nested class within a class in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)? Since there in Ruby everything is an object, an alone method is actually a method, defined on `Object` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we can define methods directly in a module without a class

First, you need to understand the differences between a class and a module in Ruby.

Let's try this :

```
module MyModule
end

MyModule.new
```

You get : `` NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for MyModule:Module ``

This is one of the most basic differences, a module is not instanciable. A module is used as a tool to divide code into logic parts, or to avoid code duplication, for instance :

```
module MyModule
  def hello
    puts "Hello world"
  end
end

class Klass1
  include MyModule
end

class Klass2
  include MyModule
end
```

Here, `Klass1` & `Klass2` will inherit the `hello` method.

Now, about nested classes.

As you saw, you can define classes inside classes, this is just a way to namespace your classes, for organization purposes :

```
class MyKlass
  class MyNestedKlass
  end

  def something
    MyNestedKlass.new 
  end
end

MyKlass::MyNestedKlass.new
```

Comment: Is it possible somehow to tell the method `something` that `MyNestedKlass` is a default namespace, to avoid prefixing all the references to it from within `something`?